# How can I find the problem with Go failed import?

Tags: postgresql, go, import, pq

While working on a Go web-app project (for learning),
I have encountered the following issue:

At the beginning, everything was alright.
I imported packages from the standard library,
used them in the code and everything worked.
up to the moment when I have tried to import the pq driver for PostgreSQL.

The actions that I did in detail:
The folder with the project files inside: notes.

project is in  the directory: C:\Users\david\go\src\github.com\davidkuch\notes

When starting, i run the command: go mod init.

I imported the standard package "database/sql".

to download the package I used: go get "github.com/lib/pq"

after that- go mod tidy

but the compiler says:could not import {package-name} no required module provides package
{package-name}

I tried to read through the docs of the related topics, but couldn't find where I did a mistake.
the same happens for another package i have tried to install from GitHub.

where should I be looking to find the problem?
as the compiler says that he "cannot find", I made a lot of effort checking naming and paths.
but I see the package exactly in the path I try to import from.
to be more precise:

After some hours of trying to fix that by myself, I ask You for some help or explanation of what is happening.

Comment: What is `{package-name}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> project is in  the directory: `C:\Users\david\go\src\github.com\davidkuch\notes`

You don't need to do that. Just make a folder like: `C:\Users\david\notes`.

Then make `C:\Users\david\notes\main.go`:

```
package main

import (
   "database/sql"
   _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
   println(sql.ErrNoRows) 
}
```

Then build:

```
go mod init something
go mod tidy
go build
```

Comment: what do you mean : go mod init something? whats something?

Comment: @davidku just literally the word `something`, or you can change to a path you like